# Bootstrap 3 not working as needed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 buttons in a container using Bootstrap 3. When the website is being viewed on a computer (Laptop or Desktop PC) they work fine. However, when the website viewed on mobile they don't function as needed.

I have added in the `.col-xs-12 .col-md-4` however the buttons are not spanning the full width of the screen and the text is not staying within the container.

Here is the code for the three buttons:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <button type="button" id="cheapestOption" class="btn btn-block-xs" aria-label="center Align">
              <a href="pricing.html" target="_blank">
                <h4>Header 4</h4>
                <p><strong>£££</strong><span>/ £££ a month</span></p>
                <ul>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                </ul>
              </a>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn " aria-label="center Align">
              <a href="pricing.html" target="_blank">
                <h4>Header 4</h4>
                <p><strong>£££</strong><span>/ £££ a month</span></p>
                <ul>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                </ul>
              </a>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn " aria-label="center Align" disabled>
                <h4>Header 4</h4>
                <p><strong>£££</strong><span>/ £££ a month</span></p>
                <p id="tempBottom"><strong>Coming Soon</strong></p>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```css
#cheapestOption {
  font-family: 'Pavanam', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border: none;
}

#cheapestOption a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#cheapestOption p {
  font-family: 'Pavanam', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#cheapestOption ul{
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#cheapestOption:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767px){
  .btn-block-xs {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

Hopefully, the images will make more sense.

[image: Mobile version of website]
[image: Desktop version of website]

Comment: A button is an inline element so it won't take up the full width of a Bootstrap column, you'll need to make it block level for that to happen. The text appears to be fine for me. Also, you're using the [`aria-label` attribute](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css) improperly - it looks like you're stuffing CSS classes or something similar in there.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `.btn-block-xs` to each `.btn` class

Try with following media-query:

> you can change media query value according to your need

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .btn-block-xs {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, do I replace ".btn-block-xs" with the ID that I have given to the button. For example, the ID is cheapestOption, so do I add that instead of ".btn-block-xs".

Comment: In CSS and ID starts with `#`, `#id`, and a class starts with `.`, `.class`.

Comment: @programmingHelp But you cannot have multiple ID. It will cause conflict in functionality. Just add the `btn-block-xs` class and css mentioned in the answer. I hope it helps you

Comment: So I have added the CSS that you gave me and added the 'class="btn-block-xs" to the button, however, it's had no effect to the output. Here is the first line for my button: <button type="button" id="cheapestOption" class="btn btn-block" aria-label="center Align" class="btn-block-xs">

Comment: It should be like this <button type="button" id="cheapestOption" class="btn btn-block-xs" aria-label="center Align" >

Comment: @JyotiPathania Still no luck. Maybe it's something I'm doing within the CSS. Underneath the 1st code snippet on my question, I have added in the CSS for the 1st button.

Comment: @programmingHelp check working demo **[here](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/rrbwkW?editors=1000)**

Comment: @JyotiPathania Could it be that there is no problem with the code, but with how I am trying to view the web page. I am using the option where you can select what the web page will look like on different devices. The one when you click inspect on a web page. I am using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

give your buttons a width for mobile in a media query (note, if you are using Bootstraps built in button classes, this should happen automatically.)

Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    button.btn{
       display:block; //force them to stack
       width:80% !important; // on small screens the buttons will be 80% screen width while 
       //leaving room for touch scrolling on the sides.
       margin: 0 auto; //to center them on small screens
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, do I replace "button.btn" with the ID that I have given to the button. For example, the ID is cheapestOption, so do I add that instead of "button.btn".

Comment: Not if you want to target more than one button. You're going to want to use a class and not an ID. IDs are single use where a class can be reused numerous times.

Comment: use classes on your buttons. You can give them unique IDs as well for binding purposes - but for applying CSS to them, use a common Class.

.btn or button.btn are acceptable, so long as you are using the button tag on all of your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Add `btn-block` for the button to span the width of the grid:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block" aria-label="center Align">
              <a href="pricing.html" target="_blank">
                <h4>Header 4</h4>
                <p><strong>£££</strong><span>/ £££ a month</span></p>
                <ul>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                </ul>
              </a>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block" aria-label="center Align">
              <a href="pricing.html" target="_blank">
                <h4>Header 4</h4>
                <p><strong>£££</strong><span>/ £££ a month</span></p>
                <ul>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                  <li> Text </li>
                </ul>
              </a>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block" aria-label="center Align" disabled>
                <h4>Header 4</h4>
                <p><strong>£££</strong><span>/ £££ a month</span></p>
                <p id="tempBottom"><strong>Coming Soon</strong></p>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```